# using returned Firebase user uid to validate

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I have a page in which I sign in a user using email n password.after that based on the `user.uid`that would be returned I push in say page_one or page_two. the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method returns `null if email and password has some error` else it returns the `user uid` so i did something like this:

```
    if(user.uid != null){ 
       //home page
       page_one; 
    } 
    else if (user.uid == null){ 
       //error page
       page_two;
    }
```

the problem I get is that whether `I sign in with correct email and password or not` it pushes me to `page_two` and then `on back press` it sends me `to page_one`tho there is `no route/navigation between them`

Comment: is page_one already opened from before? Also you will only sign in with the correct email and password, when you use `signInwithemailandpassword()` firebase auth checks if they are correct or not

Comment: nope its not open before